# Select data from one table & then rename the columns based on another table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. `TableOne` which contains two columns (name & value). `TableTwo` can contain `N no. of columns`. Number of rows in `TableOne` will be equal to number of columns in `TableTwo`.

see the below image for more information.

[image]

**What I want:**

When I run select query on `TableTwo`, the result-set should pick the column names based on `value` column of `TableOne`. We need to match column name of `TableTwo` with rows available in `TableOne` and perform transform.

So the output should look like this:

```
ColumnOne | ColumnTwo | columnThree | ColumnFour

 1           1            1             2015-05-08 15:28:22.630
 2           2            2             2015-05-07 15:28:22.630
 ................
 ................
```

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... Are you really using MySQL and SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: I won't attempt to answer this question, simply because it's a really bad example of database design. You should explore the fundamentals of the relational database model and re-design it based on what you have learned. Keeping data in 1NF (First Normal Form), is paramount to a good database design. This will cause all kinds of headaches in the future.

Comment: I didnt understand on what base you get your output ? you have column 3 and 4 .. what is unique in col 1 and col 2 ?

Comment: You need `Dynamic SQL`; code that reads one table, to create a new SQL statement to read from the next table.  This can not be done using a single query.

Comment: @JohnnyBell - Actually, *First* Normal Form is a flat file format with large scale repetition.  I think you mean *Fifth* Normal Form, usually...

Comment: @MatBailie Yes agreed, but it's dependent on the product. For example, consumer information would be better stored in 1NF, but an application model would be split down further to support the "MVC" architecture. I was simply pointing the OP in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql to generate the query to execute based on the values in the first table. Here is an example:

```
Declare @dynamicSQL nvarchar(200)
```

SET @dynamicSQL = 'SELECT ' + (SELECT stuff((select ',' + name + ' AS ' + value
     from Table1
     for xml path('')),1,1,'')) + ' FROM Table2'

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynamicSQL
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/768f9/10

Comment: I couldn't edit my original answer so I added a new one. I have added the column name changing based on the contents of the 'Value" field